# Generate automatic number in textbox

Tags: asp.net

I have a Text box and i want to generate automatic number in this on page load.

I am trying this code :

```
static int i = 1000;
TextBox1.Text = i.ToString();
      i++;
```

But when i again sign-in in my page it again start with 1000. 
I want it to generate number from where when logout from page.

thanks

Comment: You can use application state for this purpose or else go for database as suggested by [TGH](http://stackoverflow.com/users/336423/tgh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Random class for this like

```
private static Random objRandom = new Random();
    public int GetRandomNo()
    {
        return objRandom.Next();
    }
```

Comment: I want to generate sequential number so i can't use random class

Comment: so for that u have to store vale in session or store last value in any file so when u again loging than value read from file and start counting

Comment: u can store your last value in database also

Answer (score 2):

You have to store the variable somewhere to persist it between sessions. The most common choice is storing it in a database

Comment: after removing static keyword value of i doesn't change on different page load.